# What are Default Picture Names from the Hardware Camera

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I noticed that depending on how an image was taken or saved to the Windows Phone device, a different naming scheme may be used. For instance, a picture taken from the default camera application and saved to the Camera Roll will be `WP_20131108_001.jpg`, and a picture from screenshots would be `wp_ss_20131108_0001.jpg`, while the Saved Pictures album naming convention seems to be random based on where the picture came from. Is there a systematic naming scheme for pictures in different albums?

I need the ability to know when a picture was taken with my application or not in case it is used later (and it may be chosen from the PhotoChooserTask). I was thinking if there is no standard way to tell where a picture came from, then when saving an picture from my app I could put in a certain text value in the name and then check to see if a picture's name contains that text when being used in my app, and in that way flag to know whether a picture originally came from my application or not. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Album.Name` functionality of `Picture` class to get the album name/source folder where the picture came from.And while saving in cameraroll or saved pictures you can provide a custom name for your picture.

```
fileName = "Camera_" + DateTime.Now;
MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
library.SavePictureToCameraRoll(fileName, stream);
```

Comment: OK, I guess this answers my question. I will have to use a custom naming system when saving a picture from my name so I can recognize when the picture is from my app or not when it is loaded back into it from the `PhotoChooserTask` at a later time. Would you recommend checking the picture name with `.Contains` or another method. Say, I place a certain set of characters like QWERT somewhere in the name to flag that the picture is from my app. What do you think?

Comment: While saving yes, use your custom filename as mentioned above.While loading via PhotoChooserTask you can do 
`if (filename.StartsWith("Matthew")){ //do whatever }`
Contains will also do.

Comment: Thanks thats exactly what I ended up doing anyways. To note, the Completed event of CameraCaptureTask auto generates its own name which you cannot modify